# $\forall n \in \mathbb N $ prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z^n}=0$

Tags: complex-analysis, limits

$\forall n \in \mathbb N $ prove that $\displaystyle \lim_{z \to 0} \frac{1}{z^n}=0$ , $z\in \mathbb C$

I'm confused about this proof. I thought if $\lim_{z\to z_0}f(z)=0 $ then $\displaystyle\lim_{z\to z_0}\frac{1}{f(z)}=\infty$

Thus, $\lim_{z\to0}z^n =\infty$ but $\lim_{z\to0}z^n=\lim_{z\to0}0^n=0$ not according to above theory.

Could you explain me how to prove this. Help me please, Thank you very much.

Comment: The claimed limit is wrong (as you have shown).

Comment: High chances that the problem statement is wrong.

Comment: I also think it must be $z\to\infty$ or the question is wrong and your intuition is correct.

Comment: My book is wrong , It must be ${z\to \infty}$ you are right @MostafaAyaz

Answer (score 0):

Take $z=re^{i\theta}$ where $\theta$ does not depend on $r$. Then

$$\lim_{r\to0^+}(re^{i\theta})^{-n}=e^{-in\theta}\lim_{r\to0^+}r^{-n}$$ does not exist (it is not $\infty$).

Comment: Your comment that the limit is not $\infty$ is debatable.  Often in the context of complex analysis, $\infty$ is the "north pole" of the Riemann sphere, and in that case, yes, the limit would be $\infty$.

Comment: @BrianMoehring: I agree.